# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound for Ryu-oe

Tags: sdn, ryu

My goal is to have a optical LINC switch running and use Ryu-oe to control it. 
I receive the following error when I try to run Ryu-Oe instruction from [this link](https://github.com/o3project/ryu-oe).

Ryu-oe is just ryu controller with some optical extensions.

```
    File "/usr/local/bin/ryu-manager", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: msgpack-python>=0.4.0
```

Anyone knows how I can solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that the problem is solved. To be honest I don't know how it was solved. Here are some of the commands I ran:

Make sure you are in ryu-oe directory.

```
sudo -H ./run_tests.sh 
sudo ./run_tests.sh 
sudo -H python ./setup.py install
```

and then I ran `sudo ryu-manager ~/ryu-oe/ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py`.

Let me know which one worked for you so that we come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:
$  sudo pip install --upgrade msgpack-python

Comment: This is a bad an necessary answer. First the question already has an accepted answer. Second you don't provide information on why this answer solves the problem and what it does. If you want to comment on the question/answer get the necessary reputation first.